# Excel C# Workbook changes automatically

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I wrote a Excel AddIn (Office 2013), where I made reports of data from an ODBC-Connection.

I check if the current workbook contains empty Sheets. If not I add a new worbook and put all the data in it. But after finishing the Report, it Switches automatically to the first workbook ... I only use ActiveWorkbook.Activate ... Have anybody any idea why it is so and what I have to do to Change it? My Report creation goes with an Backgroundworker ... on worker_hasFinished() I also try to activate the last workbook with Application.Workbooks[Application.Workbook.Count].Activate();

Any idea?

UPDATE: Code

After a single sheet is finished, I call this method:

```
Excel.Workbook workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet targetSheet = getSheet(SheetName);
Excel.Worksheet firstSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
targetSheet.Activate();
targetSheet.Range["A1"].Select();
firstSheet.Activate();
firstSheet.Range["A1"].Select();
```

SheetName is the Name of current sheet ... The getSheet-Method is a getSheetByName-Method

```
public static Excel.Worksheet getSheet(string SheetName)
{
    Excel.Workbook workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    Excel.Worksheet returnSheet;

    foreach (Sheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
    {
        if (sheet.Name.Equals(SheetName))
        {
            return sheet;
        }
    }

    returnSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
    returnSheet.Name = SheetName;
    returnSheet.Move(After: workbook.Sheets[workbook.Sheets.Count]);

    return returnSheet;
}
```

And at least the worker_hasFinished():

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
this.ReportProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
this.ReportProgressBar.Value = 100;
this.Close();
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Count].Activate();
SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

Comment: Add more code, without it we cant help

Comment: To make sure I understand the problem: You activate `target` then `first`, and expect `target` to be active? I think you may just be confusing worksheets with workbooks, if so, but I may be misinterpreting.

Comment: Right, I active target and then the first sheet in the workbook, but I expect that the current workbook is being activated ... but after has_Finished, it activates the first workbook ...

Answer (score 0):

What is `this` in the last code snippet? Something that extends System.Windows.Forms.Form?

What does `this.Close();` do?

The way I see it, your

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Count].Activate();
```

might simply never get called, since `this` is closed before.